# Picture fading in and out ($ is not defined)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So this Is what the Html Looks like on the page http://postimg.org/image/pdzzkmifx/. What my codes do is switch the shirt color according to witch button is pressed. The buttons are the div (color and shape made in css).

Css apart from shaping the boxes isn't really relevant here.

So how do i solve the Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined error.

(im trying to make the old picture fade out and the newly selected one fade in)
(i think the problem is in the javascript)

HTML

```
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="content">
            <img id="shirt" src="images/white-t-shirt.png" />
        </div>
        <div id="choices">
            <div id="redBox" class="smallbox" onclick="red()">
                Red
            </div>
            <div id="greenBox" class="smallbox" onclick="green()">
                Blue
            </div>
            <div id="blueBox" class="smallbox" onclick="blue()">
                Blue
            </div>
            <div id="whiteBox" class="smallbox" onclick="white()">
                White
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

JavaScript

```
 function red(){color = "red"; change();}
    function green(){color = "green"; change();}
    function blue(){color = "blue"; change();}
    function white(){color = "white"; change();}

    function O(obj)
{
    if (typeof obj == 'object') 
        return obj;
    else 
        return document.getElementById(obj) 
}


     function change() 
     {
        switch (color) {
                            case "red":
                                imagePath = 'images/red-t-shirt.png';
                                break
                            case "green":
                                imagePath = 'images/green-t-shirt.png';
                                break
                            case "blue":
                                imagePath = 'images/blue-t-shirt.png';
                                break
                            case "white":
                                imagePath = 'images/white-t-shirt.png';
                                break
                        }

            O("shirt").src = imagePath;

            $(O("#shirt")).fadeOut(700, function () {
            $(this).attr('src', imagePath).fadeIn(700);
            });
    }
```

Comment: That error usually means jQuery isn't loaded, or isn't loaded before your code.

Comment: is your "view.group.js" compiled from something? And where is jQuery include? Judging from code above, there's reference to jQuery via variable "O". Why wouldn't you use that instead of "$"? And possible error: missing sharp-symbol "#" in O("shirt").

Comment: Do you have issues executing other jQuery code too?

Comment: sorry i just added the jQuery, and the jQuery code executes fine. Is uses get document by id, therefore i don't think i need to use the '#'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed your code a little bit, now it seems to be working:

**jQuery**

```
var color = '';



$(".smallbox").click(function()
 {   var color = $(this).data('val');
    switch (color) {
                        case "red":
                            imagePath = 'images/red-t-shirt.png';
                            break
                        case "green":
                            imagePath = 'images/green-t-shirt.png';
                            break
                        case "blue":
                            imagePath = 'images/blue-t-shirt.png';
                            break
                        case "white":
                            imagePath = 'images/white-t-shirt.png';
                            break
                    }

        $("#shirt").src = imagePath;
     console.log(imagePath);

        $("#shirt").fadeOut(700, function () {
        $("#shirt").attr('src', imagePath).fadeIn(700);
        });
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q8cye/)

Comment: sorry, i copied your codes word for word and there was a $ is not defined. It says error is on this line which says $(".smallbox").click(function()

Comment: Strange. Here I updated my original fiddle with images (http://jsfiddle.net/q8cye/1/) and all seems t be working fine. Is your jQuery library linked correctly and placed before other js-files/js-code?

Comment: Ok so I made a new html file and placed your new javascript codes in a <script type="text/javascript"> and copied your html codes as needed. It works in jsfiddle but it still says $ not defined at line when i run the html on chrome. $(".smallbox").click(function(). This is extremely awkward sorry i'm a beginner.

Comment: Ok, did you put the link to jQuery library before my script? Have you downloaded the jQuery library or do you use the link from another site?

Comment: Oh and by the way, did you mean that everything worked well in jsFiddle?

Comment: Yea everything worked in jsFiddle, and i have to download jQuery library? im sorry i dont know what Jquery library is.

Comment: I don't know if you have this, but add this code before any other jquery-code: `<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js  
"></script>`

Comment: You need to point (link to) the jQuery library if you have jQuery code on a page. Copy the code in my comment above and paste it in before all other JavaScript/jQuery code and I'm positive it will work.

Comment: added the jQuery code at the top before any other code, failed to load resource. I added http:, didn't find error in console, but picture doesn't change or fade in or out.

Comment: Could you link to your page?

Comment: @user3121403 Awesome! Make sure to upvote and/o mark my answer as accepted if it helped you :)